# How can I use the value of a cell in a row to chose find a column name in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this

```
   Index  Variable1  Value1  Variable2  Value2  Cat  Dog  Cow
    1      Cat        7       Sheep      7       0    0    0
    2      Sheep      2       Cat        6       0    0    0
    3      Cow        3       Dog        2       0    0    0
```

How can I efficiently populate the Cat, Dog and Cow columns with the values in the Value column when the Variable column is equal to the appropriate column name? So it looks something like this

```
Index  Variable1  Value1  Variable2  Value2  Cat  Dog  Cow
1      Cat        7       Sheep      7       7    0    0
2      Sheep      2       Cat        6       6    0    0
3      Cow        3       Dog        2       0    2    3
```

I've made a nested for loop that loops over each "Variable" column and then each row in that column that populates the data of each animal based on the value in that cell. But I'm 100% sure this is bad way of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#create variables
vals = df.filter(like = 'Value').columns
variables = df.filter(like = 'Variable').columns
animals = df.iloc[:,-3:].columns

#lump all 'Variable_' and 'Value_' into one df
res = pd.concat(df.filter(ent).set_axis(['val','var'],axis=1) for ent in zip(vals,variables))
res

    val var
0   7   Cat
1   2   Sheep
2   3   Cow
0   7   Sheep
1   6   Cat
2   2   Dog

#pivot res
out = (res
       .pivot(columns='var',values='val')
       .fillna(0)
       .astype(int)
       .filter(animals)
      )
out


var Cat Dog Cow
0   7   0   0
1   6   0   0
2   0   2   3

#final result
result = pd.concat([df.iloc[:,:-3],out],axis=1)
result


  Index Variable1   Value1  Variable2   Value2  Cat Dog Cow
0   1     Cat         7      Sheep       7       7   0   0
1   2     Sheep       2      Cat         6       6   0   0
2   3     Cow         3      Dog         2        0  2   3
```

Comment: This ended up working, took a fair bit of manipulation on my real dataset as it wasn’t as nice as the data shown here. E.g when it created val and var, they were both objects so I had to convert them to strings and floats before using the pivot step so that I didn’t get an indexing error.

Answer (score 0):

A good solution would be vectorized operations, which are generally faster than loops. NumPy comes into its own here with np.where:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'V1': ['Cat', 'Sheep', 'Cow'],
"Va1":[7, 2, 3], "v2": ['Sheep','Cat','Dog'], 'va2':[7,6,2]})

df['Cat'] = np.where(df['V1'] == 'Cat', df['Va1'], np.where(df['v2'] == 'Cat', df['va2'], 0))
df['Dog'] = np.where(df['V1'] == 'Dog', df['Va1'], np.where(df['v2'] == 'Dog', df['va2'], 0))
df['Cow'] = np.where(df['V1'] == 'Cow', df['Va1'], np.where(df['v2'] == 'Cow', df['va2'], 0))
```

[image]

Basically it checks Variable1 for the animal in question, and on matching fills with Value1, else it does the same check for Variable and Value 2, otherwise filles with 0.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`wide_to_long`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html) for reshape, then filter values by list by [`DataFrame.query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html), reshape by [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html) and last use [`DataFrame.update`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Variable1': ['Cat', 'Sheep', 'Cow'],
                   "Value1":[7, 2, 3], 
                   "Variable2": ['Sheep','Cat','Dog'], 
                   'Value2':[7,6,2],
                   'Cat':[0,0,0],
                   'Dog':[0,0,0],
                   'Cow':[0,0,0]}, index=[1,2,3])

L = ['Cat','Dog','Cow']
#or if possible select last 3 column names
#L = df.columns[-3:]
df1 = (pd.wide_to_long(df.reset_index(), ['Variable','Value'],i='index', j='tmp')
        .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
        .query("Variable in @L")
        .set_index('Variable', append=True)['Value']
        .unstack(fill_value=0))
print (df1)
Variable  Cat  Cow  Dog
index                  
1           7    0    0
2           6    0    0
3           0    3    2

df.update(df1)
print (df)
  Variable1  Value1 Variable2  Value2  Cat  Dog  Cow
1       Cat       7     Sheep       7    7    0    0
2     Sheep       2       Cat       6    6    0    0
3       Cow       3       Dog       2    0    2    3
```